# ¿Equaciones de segundo grado con tkinter entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, float

Necesito hacer un programa que resuelva equaciones de segundo grado con tkinter el problema es que las variables a las que esta asociado el Entry no funcionan a la hora de hacer el calculo

Este es un chunk del programa

```
                eqs=Tk()
                eqs.title("Equaciones")
                eqs.configure(bg="white")
                eqs.geometry("500x500")
                eqs.iconbitmap('mathslogo.ico')


                a=Label(eqs, text=("Introduce el valor de A: "),font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=1, column=0)
                av=Entry(eqs,font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=1, column=1)
                b=Label(eqs, text=("Introduce el valor de B: "),font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=2, column=0)
                bv=Entry(eqs,font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=2, column=1)
                c=Label(eqs, text=("Introduce el valor de C: "),font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=3, column=0)
                cv=Entry(eqs,font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=3, column=1)
                resultado=Label(eqs, text=("Resultado"),font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=5, column=0)
                resultadov=Label(eqs, text=(0),font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=5, column=1)

                ae=float(av.get())
                be=float(bv.get())
                ce=float(cv.get())

                def eqs_calc():
                    res=(-be+sqrt((be**2)-(4*ae*ce)))/(2*ae)
                    print (res)

                calcular=Button(eqs, text=("Calcular"),command=eqs_calc,font="Arial 12",bg="white").grid(row=4, column=0)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada no esta la ventana en bucle con `eqs.mainloop()`

Luego el error que tienes luego al convertir el string a float es muy sencillo de solucionar:

Las variables `ae`, `be` y `ce` son las que obtienen el texto del Entry, pero lo estas pidiendo cuando se esta iniciando el programa, es decir que los Entry's van a estar vacíos y de ahí salta el error al convertirlo en float, tienes que obtenerlos cuando llamas a tu función `eqs_calc` por que los valores ya van a estar colocados en el Entry

Y por ultimo tienes que actualizar el texto del Label `resultadov`, para que se muestre en pantalla de la siguiente manera: `resultadov.config(text=(res))`

El código quedaría algo así:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from math import sqrt

eqs=Tk()
eqs.title("Equaciones")
eqs.configure(bg="white")
eqs.geometry("500x500")

a = tk.Label(eqs, text=("Introduce el valor de A: "),font="Arial 12",bg="white")
a.grid(row=1, column=0)

av = tk.Entry(eqs,font="Arial 12",bg="white")
av.grid(row=1, column=1)

b = tk.Label(eqs, text=("Introduce el valor de B: "),font="Arial 12",bg="white")
b.grid(row=2, column=0)

bv = tk.Entry(eqs,font="Arial 12",bg="white")
bv.grid(row=2, column=1)

c = tk.Label(eqs, text=("Introduce el valor de C: "),font="Arial 12",bg="white")
c.grid(row=3, column=0)

cv = tk.Entry(eqs,font="Arial 12",bg="white")
cv.grid(row=3, column=1)

resultado = tk.Label(eqs, text=("Resultado"),font="Arial 12",bg="white")
resultado.grid(row=5, column=0)

resultadov = tk.Label(eqs, text=(0),font="Arial 12",bg="white")
resultadov.grid(row=5, column=1)

def eqs_calc():
    ae=float(av.get())
    be=float(bv.get())
    ce=float(cv.get())

    res=(-be+sqrt((be**2)-(4*ae*ce)))/(2*ae)
    resultadov.config(text=(res))
    print (res)

calcular = tk.Button(eqs, text=("Calcular"),command=eqs_calc,font="Arial 12",bg="white")
calcular.grid(row=4, column=0)

eqs.mainloop()
```